# Blank screen on Ionic 4 on Android 4.4.4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I followed https://ionicframework.com/docs/ to create Ionic app 4 (using Angular). I have created a basic "sidemenu" project and didn't do any modification to the default code and build the app and APK file created successfully.

But when I installed it on my phone ( running Android 4.4.4 and installed successfully ) it shows blank page ( it showed the splash screen and then blank page )

Documentation ( https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/browser-support ) says this support Andoird 4.4.

I'm running on

```
Ionic version 4.12.0
Cordova version 7.1.0
```

What am I missing? Please help me, I searched everywhere but didn't find a proper answer

Comment: Does anything log in the command line when using remote devices ?

Comment: i just follow the document to create the app and build the app... when build i got the APK file which i used to install on the device

Comment: You can debug your app using chrome. https://ionic.zone/debug/remote-debug-your-app this guide should help you out. But as per the information you have mentioned all I can think is that your that your cordova and android version may not be compatible. But per this document it seems that it is not the case https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/

Comment: Do you have  log when  u launch app ?

Comment: Check `config.xml` for `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />`.

Comment: it is already in 19

Comment: Maybe a problem with cordova.js loading. Do you have a log?

Comment: @user2609021 Did you get any solution so far because I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced same issue i have tried below mentioned points:-

First Remove webview plugin

`ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 
 npm uninstall @ionic-native/ionic-webview`

and then reinstall

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 
 npm install @ionic-native/ionic-webview`

If it still not working

Down grade you cordova version to 8.1.1

and remove platform and add android 6.4.0 platform

`ionic cordova platform rm android 
 ionic cordova platform add android@6.4.0`

Comment: I am not able to build android after installing cordova-android version 6.4.0 due to error.

Comment: I am getting an error like "error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6"

Comment: remove platform and first update your global cordova version and try to add it again as latest android platform